# How to get balance of a bitcoin p2sh address?

Tags: balance, p2sh

I send some BTCs to a p2sh address. How can I get the balance of the address?

Local regtest mode

Comment: I've provided an answer... let me know if you specifically wanted to know how to do it with Bitcoin core though

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for it in [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) or similar service.

Eg for an [example address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) 3P14159f73E4gFr7JterCCQh9QjiTjiZrG you can see [the result of such a query here](https://blockchain.info/address/3P14159f73E4gFr7JterCCQh9QjiTjiZrG).